# Formatting Stripe's Timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

What I thought would be some simple timestamp formatting is giving me a bit of grief. Probably just a silly mistake though!

In my Rails 4 app, I'm retrieving data from Stripe's API. I'm having an issue with the timestamps that they return.

If I just output the timestamp like this:

```
@subscription.trial_end
```

then I have no problem. But if I want to format the timestamp like this:

```
@subscription.trial_end.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

then I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `strftime' for 1384109487:Fixnum
```

Can I use `strftime` on this value?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry - got it sorted:

```
Time.at(@subscription.trial_end).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: If you're using Rails, you probably want to use `Time.zone.at` instead to ensure that the Time returned is in your application's timezone as opposed to the server's.